# Exported Blender Animations Not Playing

Tags: animation, export

I made an animation of my Character walking with a gun and exported it as a FBX file. After viewing the exported file in a 3D viewer, i saw that the animation for my player walking was playing and my gun that was supposed to sway with the player, wouldn't play. In Blender they both worked perfectly, syncing up to make the animation, but upon exporting, something went wrong and the gun won't move.

Here it is in Blender: https://gyazo.com/182760c52933b82c2a1dadbac8d4beaa

Here is is when exported as FBX: https://gyazo.com/b18021d25a086712f540d74b5ed04965

As you can see, the gun isnt moving. I didn't select certain aspects to export, i just exported the whole thing. My thought was that it only registers my character's animation and disregards the other one for the gun after exporting it. They are two separate objects, the gun i copied and pasted from another one of my blender files into my character file, then i begun the animation process. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, please use the built in tools to add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) and [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) to your post. Read the [tour] and the [help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our site also, there is much useful information there about how this site works, and how to get the most use out of it.

Comment: It's possible that your gun doesn't have an action assigned to it. Or it's parenting broke during export.

Comment: Both of them have an assigned action:

https://gyazo.com/d4e8596d5ed8d9c4c4b81f6f5c00cc47

These pretty much do the same exact thing, one was for the character and one was for the gun. I've tried exporting them both on the same action and different action but get the same result